# Angular don't see changes in JSON file after deployment

Tags: json, angular, typescript, deployment, web-deployment

After deploying my application on angular, it doesn't consider the modifications of my json file and still calls the previous value

I have this JSON file in assets directory to store server address

```
{ "serverip":"http://192.168.0.1:8081/api"}
```

and i use it in environment.prod.ts file like this

```
import server from '../assets/server.json'

export const environment = {
production= true,
url: server.serverip
}
```

it's fine but when i change json file, everything stays as it was, angular still calls the previous address.I want to be able to modify the json file according to the new server address without having to rebuild project.
how do i fix it?

Comment: Mostly your files are cached, try to perform cache bust, your issue will be resolved.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you’re trying to change this file directly in the assets folder of the dist folder? That won’t work - as you are importing this file, so it will simply get compiled during build time. If you need this dynamic, use a http call to actually get the json runtime.

Comment: thanks mike, but using an http call to get the json runtime requires me to make this call for every http request I want to make, seems a bit cumbersome

Answer (score -1):

If you want it to work the way you have it where you import it, before your build you'll have to replace the contents with what you want. After the build happens whatever was in the JSON file gets compiled into your main application.